# Run MBUnit Tests using Resharper 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2012, mbunit, resharper-8.1

I need to run MBUnit Tests using Resharper 8.1 in in visual studio 2012.
I couldn't find any resharper plugin for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Sandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using  Icarus test runner

Comment: Please give a link to understand what is lcarus test runner